# How To Use WebService In Windows Smart Phone 6?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, smart-device, smart-device-framework

I am Developing one Windows Smart Phone - 6 Application using C# in .Net 3.5 Framework. And I have created one Webservice project using  ASP.Net Web Service Application 3.5. Into this Webservice project I have define Service1.asmx. Now I would like to call Webmethod "HelloWorld" on Button Click. Here is code.

### Service1.asmx

```
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebService1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

### And Button Click Event

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebService1.Service1 myService = new WebService1.Service1();
        string str = myService.HelloWorld();
    }
```

I am Getting  Error On This Line

```
WebService1.Service1 myService = new WebService1.Service1();
```

**Please Give Me Guidance As I am Very New In This.**

Thanks In Advance

**Pratik Bhatt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

Error Was Occurring Because The Smart Device Emulator has No Access Permission for internet(network)so you have to install Microsoft Active Sync to connect emulator to network

Thanks Ralf Ehlert For Suggesting.....

Answer (score 0):

Use the add web reference dialog from visual studio and point them to your hosted service. The dialog creates the consuming client based on the generated WSDL.

Your approach doesn't work because hosting a webservice and consuming one uses a different set of classes.

Comment: Hello Sir,Thanks For Your Quick Response.We knew That There Is Version Problem.Can You Please Explain Or Guide How Can I add Web Service In my Smart-Phone  Application (Windows Phone - 6) whatever Way,Kindly Suggest.Waiting For Your Valuable Reply..Thanks Again